# Progress - loading window on NSDocument application

Tags: nswindow, progress, nsdocument

I need to show an NSWindow with a progress bar in it while the file is being loaded in an NSDocument application. The `makeKeyAndOrderFront:` for the "loading progress window" does not seem to be invoked inside `readFromURL:ofType:error:` since, probably, the app is not fully initialized at that time. What should be the best practice to load a loading progress window in an NSDocument application

Answer (score -2):

After some research, I found [this solution](http://pnelsoncomposer.com/software/NewbieFAQ.html) That worked fine for me.

Comment: A) that's not an answer, and B) the link is broken and points at a musician's website!